# Trying to sort a Double Collection

Tags: java, arrays, collections, double

I am trying to sort a *Collection*. I cant seem to get my code to work with what I have found online.

Collection:

```
[104.131119, 104.188937, 93.174548, 100.533096, 97.902247, 98.608619, 93.380054, 106.690206, 106.461181, 108.190245]
```

Code:

```
Collection<Double> csvData = new ArrayList<Double>();

//logic of reading csv file and adding data to collection

//Adding into the collection using 
csvData.add(csvValue);

//sorting 
Collections.sort(csvData); // error, The method sort(List<T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (Collection<Double>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try doing `List<Double> csvData = new ArrayList<Double>();` instead of `Collection<Double> csvData = new ArrayList<Double>();`? The error is telling you the `sort()` method takes a parameter of type `List`, not of type `Collection`.

Comment: `Collection` is unordered, so it makes no sense to sort the data and store it back in a `Collection`, because the data might just end up unordered again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must declare the variable like this:

```
List<Double> csvData = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

The error is clear: the `Collections.sort()` method expects a `List` object, a `Collection` won't work.